# pandas найти значение из ячейки-списка

Tags: python, pandas

Есть датафрейм, где в `transactions_ids` располагаются списки

```
  month  transactions_ids 
0     1         [0, 5, 1]        
1     2            [7, 4]    
2     3    [8, 10, 9, 11]     
3     6               [2]                  
4     9               [3]
```

Требуется вернуть те строки датафрейма, где в списках `transactions_ids` присутствует определенное значение

Как это сделать?

Comment: А как вы пробовали это сделать?

Comment: я вообще без понятия, как это сделать, я только смог найти, решение, где наоборот значения из искомого списка совпадают со значением ячейки

Answer (score 1):

можно сделать так:

```
value_to_find=7
res = df[df["transactions_ids"].apply(lambda x: value_to_find in x)]
```

res:

```
   month transactions_ids
1      2           [7, 4]
```